# Erro ao tentar criar uma nova tabela MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou me deparando com um erro ao tentar criar uma tabela em meu banco de dados no MySql.

Li sobre esse erro em outras ocorrências aqui no stackoverflow, e parece que ele ocorre quando você tenta utilizar uma palavra chave do MySql onde ela não deve ser utilizada, mas não acho que isso está ocorrendo no meu código.

Código:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_vendas (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id_produto` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id_usuario` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `email_usuario` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `data_compra` DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto`) REFERENCES tbl_produtos(`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES tbl_usuario(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Erro:

> #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'CURRENT_DATE,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto`) REFERENCE' na linha 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na definição da data:

```
`data_compra` DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
```

`CURRENT_DATE` não é suportado como valor por defeito, como a documentação indica:

> DEFAULT
>
> Specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the
>   default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an
>   expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default
>   for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or
>   CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   as the default for a TIMESTAMP column. See Section 11.3.5, “Automatic
>   Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP”.

[Link para a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

A exceção à regra é o valor `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` como valor por defeito que pode ser utilizado numa coluna do tipo `TIMESTAMP`, assim como a documentação indica.

Comment: Não funcionou! Com o `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` me retorna o erro: `#1067 - Valor padrão (default) inválido para 'data_compra'`

Comment: @Francisco Sim era como eu estava a alterar. Para ser `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` tem de ser numa coluna do tipo `TIMESTAMP` e não `DATE`